# Google oauth2.0, required parameter is missing: grant_type

Tags: c++, oauth-2.0

I follow Google document to make a "sign in with Google" for my company desktop app, document link: 
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp

The problem is when I send a post request to retrieve access_token, I always receive this error:

"error": "invalid_request"

"error_description": "Required parameter is missing: grant_type"

I did search Google for a few days but have no idea what's happening. Forgive me if this is a dumb question, I have no knowledge of http.

This is my code. In my code, I use libraries from this link:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/66625/A-Fully-Featured-Windows-HTTP-Wrapper-in-C

```
#include "RegExp.h"
#include "StringProcess.h"
#include "WinHttpClient.h"

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void main(void)
{
    WinHttpClient client(L"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token");

    //data of post request
    string data = "";

    data += "code=";
    string code = "some_code";
    data += code;

    data += "&client_id=";
    string client_id = "my_app_id";
    data += client_id;

    data += "&client_secret=";
    string client_secret = "my_app_secret";
    data += client_secret;

    data += "&redirect_uri";
    string redirect_uri = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob";
    data += redirect_uri;

    data += "&grant_type=";
    string grant_type = "authorization_code";
    data += grant_type;


    client.SetAdditionalDataToSend((BYTE *)data.c_str(), data.size());

    //header of post request
    wstring headers = L"Content-Length: ";
    headers += L"\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
    wchar_t szHeaders[MAX_PATH * 10] = L"";
    swprintf_s(szHeaders, MAX_PATH * 10, headers.c_str(), data.size());
    client.SetAdditionalRequestHeaders(szHeaders);

    //send request and print response
    client.SendHttpRequest(L"POST");

    wstring httpResponseHeader = client.GetResponseHeader();
    wstring httpResponseContent = client.GetResponseContent();

    char content[10000];
    sprintf(content, "%ls", httpResponseContent.c_str() );

    char header[10000];
    sprintf(header, "%ls", httpResponseHeader.c_str());

    cout << header  << endl;
    cout << content << endl;

    system("pause");
}
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Shouldn't there be an = after redirect_uri, and shouldn't the redirect_uri be URL-encoded?

Comment: @immibis thank you
1/ I add an "=", still no change
2/ you mean this: "headers += L"\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"; ?

Comment: No, immibis means the colons need to be URL encoded (`=urn%3Aietf%3A` etc) in the value for redirect_uri.

Comment: @ 1201ProgramAlarm: I try modifying the uri but still no change

Answer (score 0):

Your redirect_uri MUST be a [real URI](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3) and must match the  if the "redirect_uri" parameter was included in the  authorization request as described in Section 4.1.1 ([RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#page-29)), and their values MUST be identical. A uri must be like scheme:[//[user:password@]host[:port]][/]path